# Places added newly through google places api but the places added to app not to google db

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I have added new basketball court to the Google Database 2 days ago but it's not added while I searched for that particular court in google maps . I don't know  how to track the status of the court whether it passes the moderation process . I explored it in google places add api but it gives that only the scope of the app in the response .

Also the newly added places is not reflected directly in nearby (app-scope)api. I have got this app-specific court when I pass type params to the api . Then I need to concatenate these two results to get reflected to the application. Am I right?

Please guide me in optimal path to be listed in my application as well as Google's database.

Also Please help me to find my query below. 
How can I track the status of newly added places in google .

Please Help me 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Place Add documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place#add-place-overview) itself, it is stated that:

> When you add a place, the new place is available immediately in Nearby
>   Searches initiated by your application. The new place also enters a
>   moderation queue to be considered for Google Maps. A newly-added place
>   does not appear in Text Search or Radar Search results, or to other
>   applications, until it has been approved by the moderation process.

So it means that you can see the places that you add. Just take note that you are the only one that can see this as of the time you created/add. in order for the others to view it or make visible, it needs to pass a moderation process. If your add places did not show up after a week or more, then maybe it did not pass the process.

Just read the above link to know more about it.

**UPDATE**

Unfortunately, [Place Add](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/add-place) has been deprecated on June 30, 2017 and will stop working on June 30, 2018. So you cannot use this method anymore. For further details please refer to the corresponding [geo blog post](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2017/06/announcing-deprecation-of-place-add.html).

Comment: But how do you know if a place passed the moderation process? No mail are sent